# CDT Parse Makefile Output

Tags: c, eclipse, makefile, eclipse-cdt

I am using Eclipse as an IDE to help me develop a Arduino Program. I am using the [Arduino Makefile](https://github.com/sudar/Arduino-Makefile) to build my project and have Eclipse use an "external" makefile. The makefile is pretty in-depth which sets build variables during the building process. However the CDT error highlighter is highlighting errors because the makefile sets the build variables. Is there a way to have Eclipse run the makefile and then parse the output to see if there are any errors in the project?

**Makefile**

```
BOARD_TAG    = uno
MONITOR_PORT = /dev/ttyACM*

include $(ARDMK_DIR)/Arduino.mk
```

Answer (score 0):

as far as I know, nope! This would be quite a task anyways, given the recursive nature of CDT managed make builds. You can define preprocessor symbols if you'd like under **C/C++ General->Preprocessor Include Paths->Entries->GNU C->CDT User Settings Entries (treat as built-in).**

**Proposed Solution**

- Have your **makefile** generate a header file with these values before compilation using some sort of bash script

**Implementation Example**

My main project at work right now uses Eclipse-CDT-External-Makefile. We have several 'CONFIG_DO_ABC' type variables. We generate a config.h. Here is a boiled down example.

**Makefile**

```
include config.mk

all:
    ./config.awk config.mk > config.h
    gcc main.c -o main.o    

clean:
    rm -r *.o main
```

**config.mk**

```
CONFIG_A  := 1
CONFIG_B  := 2
CONFIG_C  := 3
```

**config.awk**

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
BEGIN {
    print "/* Generated by config.awk; do not edit */"
    print "#ifndef CONFIG_H"
    print "#define CONFIG_H"
}
$1 ~ /^CONFIG_/ && $2 ~ /^:?=$/ { print "#define", $1, $3 }
END { print "#endif" }
```

**main.c (illustrative example)**

```
#include "config.h"

int main (void) {
    return CONFIG_A;
}
```

**(make console output)**

```
make all 
./config.awk config.mk > config.h
gcc main.c -o main.o
```

this works very well for my use cases, especially for #ifdef vars (e.g. #ifdef HALT_ON_BUG, or something).

you will have to use a more complicated script than the config.awk here for your string use; but hopefully this is enough to get started.